# OpenGL and GLFW - Do I need shaders to draw a point?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw

I am working through a [book on OpenGL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159863528X), and I am stuck on the third chapter.  The following code should open a window and draw a single dot in the center.

The window shows up, `glClearColor` and `glClear` seem to be working, but no dot.  [This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/glsl-default-shaders/28826#28826) leads me do believe I may need to compile and link simple vertex and fragment shaders.

The book has made no mention of them, but do I need shaders?  Am I missing something else with how I am drawing the dot?  Something with the window?  The book uses some `WIN32` thing for windowing, I am using Linux Mint 17.1

Code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ( (char*)NULL + (i) )

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
  fputs(description, stderr);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
  if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

int main(void) {
  GLFWwindow* window;
  glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
  if (!glfwInit()) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  glfwSwapInterval(1);
  glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

  if (glewInit()) {
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

  float ratio;
  int width, height;
  glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
  ratio = width / (float) height;
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

  GLfloat vertex [] = {0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f};
  GLuint m_vertexBuffer;
  glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertexBuffer);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, &vertex[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glPointSize(10.0f);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }

  glfwDestroyWindow(window);
  glfwTerminate();
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Also, I am compiling with `g++ main.cpp -lGL -lglfw -lGLU -lGLEW`

I have OpenGL 4.5 installed, but am opening a fixed-pipeline context.

Comment: No, you don't need shaders, unless you're using OpenGL 3 or 4 (which you'd know because you have to ask for it) in which case everything needs a shader.

Comment: (In OpenGL 3 they made shaders mandatory, which allowed them to remove a whole lot of non-shader stuff, drastically simplifying OpenGL but also making it harder to get started)

Comment: Aha, thank you!  I have 4.5 installed, and this book is apparently using version 2.  Chapter six is `programmable pipeline` where it starts with 3+.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an OpenGL 3.3 context in GLFW 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113270/how-do-i-create-an-opengl-3-3-context-in-glfw-3)

Comment: Even if you have 4.5 installed, you'll get a backwards-compatible OpenGL 2 context if you don't specifically ask for 4.5, that supports all the OpenGL 2 stuff. (Otherwise old games would have broken when OpenGL 3 came out!)

Answer (score 2):

From your code:

```
GLfloat vertex [] = {0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f};
```

Since you use the fixed function pipelione and never set any matrices, both the projection and the modelView matrix will be left at the default, and the point (0, 0, -2) is outside fo the viewing volume. Try (0, 0, 0) instead.

If the book uses excatly this code with exactly that vertex coordinates, you'd better search for another one. You should also consider learning "modern" GL instead. The fixed-funciton pipeline basically has been superseeded by shaders in GL2.0 *a decade ago*.

Comment: I tried this, still no dot.  Thanks anyway, but I'm going to get through the chapters on math, then just worry about drawing dots with modern GL.  GLSL FTW.